# Including Arrays from one Script into Another Script

Tags: arrays, include, powershell-1.0

I have multiple scripts that use the same arrays to define file paths and grab file dates. For example:

```
$file1path = "C:\filepath\file1.exe"
$file1date = (Get-Childitem $file1path).LastWriteTime.ToString("m/d/yyyy")
```

These scripts then use these arrays to build out .ps1 checksum scripts and VB monitoring script files with updated file date information as file versioning is a bit of a joke here. I got to thinking that I could simplify these scripts by putting these 200ish lines of arrays into just 1 master array file and then these other build scripts could just have some sort of include line to pull the arrays it calls from this master script.

Is there any good way for me to do this? I am constrained by needing to use PowerShell v1 in our environment unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dot source the contents of one .ps1 file into another.  This allows you to effectively "include" any variables and functions defined in a common .ps1 into whatever .ps1 script files you dot source into.  For example:

```
Common.ps1 contents
-------------------
$files = @(Get-ChildItem c:\filepath\*.exe)

Doit.ps1 contents
-----------------
. .\common.ps1
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fileDate = $file.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Still fairly new to PowerShell, so I will see what I can do with this.